# Excel VBA - Copying multiple ranges and pasting them in order of selection without overwriting

Tags: excel, vba

So I have no VBA background, but I have managed to put this together by scouring the internet. It is for a workbook where the ultimate goal is to have users (Engineers) select certain checkboxes. When they are done (And there will be a lot of checkboxes), they click the button "Build" and depending on their selections, they will generate a new worksheet or new workbook (Haven't decided on that one yet) with all the selected information pasted into it, in order.

Here is the code as it stands:

```
Sub Merge()

    If Range("F3") = True Then

            Sheets("Data").Select
            Range("A1:A8").Select
           Selection.Copy

            Sheets("UI").Select
            Cells(1, 1).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
               False, Transpose:=False
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
               False, Transpose:=False
        Else
              MsgBox "Part 1 - Failed."
    End If

    If Range("F6") = True Then

            Sheets("Data").Select
            Range("A10:A17").Select
            Selection.Copy

            Sheets("UI").Select
            Cells(10, 1).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
               False, Transpose:=False
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
               False, Transpose:=False
        Else
            MsgBox "Part 2 - Failed"
    End If

    If Range("F9") = True Then

            Sheets("Data").Select
            Range("A19:A26").Select
            Selection.Copy

            Sheets("UI").Select
            Cells(19, 1).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
               False, Transpose:=False
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
               False, Transpose:=False
        Else
            MsgBox "Part 3 - Failed"
    End If

End Sub
```

and here is the file in my google drive if that makes things easier for you:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bza853yM-QSMSlFWbElBc1dsbGM/edit?usp=sharing

Currently, it is pasting the ranges that are "True" into pre-defined cell ranges.
However, what i would like is if Red = True and Green = True, that red is pasted into A1:A8, and Green would be pasted into A10:A18. Similarly, if Blue and Green are True, or just Blue or Green are true, they paste into A1:A8 and the next "True" statement pastes under them. This way you could have any number of True statements and they will paste in order, with only 1 row spaced between them instead of 8 or 20 rows.

I looked over this website and others but didn't find anything. So i'm not sure if this is possible or that i'm too ignorant on the subject to search for the words of the concept i'm looking for.

Thanks for your wisdom!
-Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pasting your copies into a static Range, you could find the next blank cell on your "UI" sheet, and paste the next set of results to that.

Code to find next blank cell...

```
Sheets("UI").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Comment: So I changed the Cells part for the Range/End/Offset lines your said for all three colors. When i click run, the row displayed is row: 1048576. and i get "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error." I click Debug and the row "Selection.Offset(1,0).Select" is highlighted.

Comment: Update - So i looked up this End.xlDown command and found something that kind of worked. I changed the 3rd line of your suggestion to 'code' Selection.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Select 'code' this worked, except that it now starts the paste in A2. Would I have to make an "If-Else" statement with each iteration to check to see if A1 is blank and if so, paste to there. If Not, then the End/Offset code? Or is that not necessary?

Comment: With your changes, you should just be able to change the A2 above to A1.  It should then find the starting blank spot.